# Setting DefaultDataPath and DefaultLogPath programmatically (Using SQL Statements to initialize the path)

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, database-project

My Query is regarding using NOT hard coded File Locations to initialize the the Variables DefaultDataPath and DefaultLogPath. Prior to adopt Database Projects as our standard Deployment and Database Management Tools and migrating our existing Scripts to Database projects we have been using the SET of CREATE and INITIALIZE scripts for Setting up Database. We are having following SQL Query to CREATE the Database with the FILE location:

```
SET @data_path = (SELECT SUBSTRING(filename, 1, CHARINDEX(N'master.mdf', LOWER(filename)) - 1) 

          FROM sys.sysaltfiles WHERE dbid = 1 AND fileid = 1);

set @mdb_file=@data_path + 'CF_DB.mdf'
set @cfdata='CF_DB_Data'
set @cflog='CF_DB_Log'
set @ldf_file=@data_path + 'CF_DB_log.ldf'
declare @sql nvarchar(500)
set @sql = 'CREATE DATABASE [CF_DB]  ON (NAME = ' + quotename(@cfdata) + ',FILENAME =' + quotename(@mdb_file) + ',SIZE = 53, FILEGROWTH = 10%) LOG ON (NAME =' + quotename(@cflog) + ',FILENAME = ' + quotename(@ldf_file) + ', SIZE = 31, FILEGROWTH = 10%)COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
exec(@sql)
```

Here we are trying to figure out the location of MDF file for MASTER DB and using the same location to CREATE DATABASE.

Problem: With the scripts generated (after Deploy action) , there is an auto Generated SQLCMD variables , initialized with some default path (hardcoded one ) or Empty strings (which are using Default Datafile path used by SQL Server 2008 or 2005).

```
:setvar DatabaseName "CF"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER2008\MSSQL\DATA\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER2008\MSSQL\DATA\"
```

We need to make it work like our existing system. We need to know path of MASTER DB data and log files and using the same path to initialize DefaultDataPath and DefaultLogPath. We can't go with PreDeployment scripts because Database settings are done by Database Project generated script before embedding PreDeploymentScript in the final Deploy Scripts.

NEXT big thing: Developer need to switch to SQLCMD Mode in SQL Server Management Studio to run the scripts generated by DB Project. This is our implementation Team's requirement NOT TO USE SQLCMD mode to setup DATBASE. To overcome these step, I need to modify the generated SQL file and use SQL Variables instead of SQLCMD variables. Can we generate the clean SQL Statements and keeping automation script generation intact? I know both of these issues are corelated thus the solution for one is going to Fix the other one.

Thanks for any good suggestions or help upon the above discussions.

Regards

Sumeet

Answer (score 1):

When SSDT/VS generates the SQL file, it actually runs some queries against the server you've told it to connect to. The settings you're getting here for example...

```
:setvar DatabaseName "CF"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER2008\MSSQL\DATA\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER2008\MSSQL\DATA\"
```

Are obtained from server settings from the target database connection you specified in your publish file/profile.

On the server that you are using to generate your scripts, open regedit.exe and search for the keys "**DefaultLog**" and "**DefaultData**" under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft** - they should be in the same location. See if they match the settings your scripts are generating.

You can change these on the server/your PC (where ever you are pointing to) and it will generate the locations you enter in your generate SQL Scripts. Be cautious naturally around a server you do not own, or that is in use for production etc as this will change a setting on the server which points SQL Server where to place new databases. This is a different setting it seems than the one you enter in SQL Server properties -> Database Settings.

Hope that helps!

Comment: To get around the SQLCMD issue, could you use DACPAC deploys instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how best to handle your file path, though I suspect you will want to not use the Default File Path setting and instead use a new file path that you can control through a variable.

It sounds to me like you're trying to have the developers update their local machines easily. My recommendation would be to build out some batch files that do the following:

- Set the PATH to include the location for MSBuild.exe
- Get the location for your master database
- Pass that location in to a variable
- Run the MSBuild command to set your path variables to the local master path
  and publish the database/changes.

Overall, that sounds like more trouble than it's really worth. I'd recommend that you send out a SQL Script to all of the developers getting them to properly set up their Default Data/Log paths and just use the defaults.

I do recommend that you look into setting up some batch files to run the MSBuild commands. You'll have a lot easier time getting the database builds to your developers without them generating scripts and running them locally. Alternatively, you could have them change their SSMS defaults to set SQLCMD mode on for their connections.  SSDT made this a little nicer because it won't run at all without SQLCMD mode turned on - eliminated a lot of the messiness from VS2008/VS2010 DBProjects.

I used something like the following to build and deploy when we were on DB Projects:

```
msbuild /m .\MyDB\MyDB.dbproj /t:build
msbuild /m .\MyDB\MyDB.dbproj /t:deploy /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;" /p:TargetDatabase="MyDB"
```